# C++ virtual destructor cause base method to be called

Tags: c++, multithreading, polymorphism, destructor, virtual-functions

I wrote this simple example to get whats happening
I want all logic to be implemented in base class and derived specific methods in derived class, so:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
    base() : stop(false) {}

    virtual ~base()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor base\n"; 

        if( handle.joinable() )
        {
            stop = true;
            handle.join();
        }
    }

    void runThread() { handle = std::thread( worker, this ); }

    virtual void stopThread() { std::cout << "Base stopThread\n"; }

protected:
    std::atomic<bool> stop;

    std::thread handle;

    static void worker( base *me )
    {
        while( me->stop == false )
        {
            std::cout << "Working\n";
            me->stopThread(); // this one in called as derived
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(1) );
        }

        me->stopThread(); // this one is called as base
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:

    ~derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor derived\n"; 
    }

private:
    void stopThread() { std::cout << "derived stopThread\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    derived der;
    der.runThread();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(3) );
}
```

and the result:

```
Working
derived stopThread
Working
derived stopThread
Working
derived stopThread
Destructor derived
Destructor base
Base stopThread <-- hmmm
```

So everything works fine except base destructor - it calls base::stopThread. Why is this happening? If I make it pure virtual I get an exception.

I can fix this by moving destructor to derived class, but this is not clear because I want all logic to be implemented in base class.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing to do with threads : the dynamic type of an object inside its destructor is its static type, since any derived part has already been destroyed.

Comment: By the way, the fact that pure virtual function gave you an exception should've hinted you.

Comment: As a side note, rules vary depending on the languages so you have to learn the rules for your language if you want to do some advanced stuff.

Comment: This design is bad in any language; what does `base` represent? What is the abstraction?

Comment: @curiousguy some device class with poll logic and interface, derived are different versions and models. When software stopped it should be properly disabled

Answer (score 4):

virtual methods do not dispatch to the most derived implementation within a constructor or a destructor. The reason for this is that by the time the destructor of `base` has been called the `derived` instance has already been destroyed.

More formally, as Quentin said in the comments, virtual methods dispatch to the static type of the instance, inside a constructor or destructor.

Comment: "The reason for this is that by the time the destructor of base has been called the derived instance has already been destroyed." I think for clarity, you can add to this: "And conversely, when the constructor of `base` has been called, the `derived` part has not yet been constructed.

Comment: so the only way to resolve this is to move destructor to derived class?

Comment: @FedorKryukov, you might need to rethink your design now, knowing that (sometimes quite inconvenient) fact about non-polymophic calls from constructor/destructor. On any rate, joining thread in destructor is not neccessarily the best idea.

Comment: @FedorKryukov - you could move all the stop logic into the base class, that way it will be fine for you to call it from the destructor.

Comment: Got it. I'll join them from somewhere else )

Comment: @Sean its impossible in my project because derived classes implement various hardware devices with different stop commands, so I'll make joins from an object that constructs them. Thanks !

Comment: Actually, virtual functions dispatch use the dynamic type from inside constructors and destructors too. "_to the most derived implementation_" inside ctors and dtors is simply the one of class being constructed or destroyed.

Comment: hi again, I think std::unique_ptr custom deleter function would be useful here, looks like it runs before derived instance deleted